# Certificate management on a MS CRM Dynamics Online instance

Tags: certificate, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Having spent a week on research on this topic I have no option but to ask this:

How can one add a certificate to a MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Online? I can't just go and add the certificate to the servers key chain as this from of CRM provides no means to do so.

I need to set the certificate for a CRM plugin that will need a specific public key for signing and encrypting its messages to a external interface.

I hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of research it seems that there is no sane way to add your own certificates to the "server" of a Dynamics Online instance.

For my case we ended up creating another server to act as a "signing and crypting"-Proxy.